# An error occurred while creating the database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am trying to create a new JavaDB. I have added the Java DB Drivers into Libraries, but it's still throwing out an error when creating a new Database under services.

I downloaded and defined db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin

[image]

And I defined the driver files here:

[image]

I clicked create database here:

[image]

And filled in this form:

[image]

After I clicked on it, it shows like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: what Java version are you using? some drivers seems to be compiled against java 9, have you tried another prior Derby version?

Comment: you can also add the driver via right clicking in libraries and choose add java db driver from the list.

Comment: i am using JDK-15

Comment: but I do not want to add insight to the project I need to add a database through Netbeans service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem.

I don't know why it's not working. But I changed Derby version `10.15` to `10.2`, and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with the Derby release notes, I think you are missing the Derby tools

> In addition, the derbytools.jar library is
> now required when running the network server and/or when using Derby
> DataSources.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't download the 10.15.2.0 version

Just download from the below, and it will work fine:

https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10_14_2_0.cgi